# Backing up Apache access logs to S3

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, amazon-s3

I am trying to backup Apache 2.4.27 logs on Amazon Linux 2016.03. I am trying to do so without writing a shell script, and I do not want to configure AWS access key and secret key on my Linux machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use **[EC2 IAM Role](https://aws.nz/best-practice/ec2-instance-roles/)** that gives your EC2 instance the required credentials without having to manage Access/Secret keys.
2. If you want to get away without a shell script you can feed the logs to **CloudWatch Logs** using [`awslogs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html).

However uploading your Apache logs to S3 is a simple command like `aws s3 cp /var/log/http/... s3://some-bucket/...` - that can be called e.g. from your weekly/daily `logrotate` config or from `cron`. That can hardly be called a "shell scripting" ;)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: My default here would be an IAM role as you said, plus the [cloudwatch logs agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html). Cloudwatch logs is typically better than putting logs into an S3 bucket.

Comment: Went ahead with s3 command line. Working smoothly.